# say if remains 30 min in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

i have sun.js to count sunset and sunrise and midnight, and i want to display the sunrise time only if remains 30 min (to sun shine) then hidden after sunrise (not show sunset and midnight), and the same thing with sunset and midnight ,if remain 30 min from any one of them.
i don't know how i can say if == remains 30 min from now .

the code whow print sunrise and others from the sun.js:

```
var date = new Date();
var times = suntimes.getTimes(date, [43, -80], -5);
document.write('Sunrise = '+ times.sunrise);
document.write('Sunsite = '+ times.sunsite);
document.write('midnight = '+ times.midnight);
```

and i want to put checkbox in the page to start this code (stop default).

all code in javascript.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Time in Javascript are stored as milliseconds, so calculating difference is just subtracting these.

Below is a simple example that shows how many seconds, minutes, hours until 5'oclock tomorrow.

```js
var refDate = new Date("2019-03-21T17:00:00");

function r(id) {
  return document.querySelector("#"+id);
}

function tickTock() {
  r("refdate").innerText = refDate.toLocaleString()
  var seconds = refDate.getTime() - Date.now();
  r("seconds").innerText = Math.trunc(seconds / 1000);
  r("minutes").innerText = Math.trunc(seconds / 1000/ 60);
  r("hours").innerText =  Math.trunc(seconds / 1000 / 60 / 60);
}

tickTock();
setInterval(tickTock, 1000);
```

```html
<div>Refernce Date: <span id="refdate"></span></div>
<div>seconds to go: <span id="seconds"></span></div>
<div>minutes to go: <span id="minutes"></span></div>
<div>hours to go: <span id="hours"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanx, but i don't want to see remain seconds or min, i wan' to see the sunset time like 06:15 ? And new date from device clock.